# Picasso load different images in portrait and landscape mode

Tags: android, screen-orientation, picasso

I have a fragment which downloads an image using Picasso and displays it in ImageView. Problem is the image is in portrait mode and if the phone changes to landscape mode the same image gets stretched. I looked for solutions but what I got in general sense is to simply rotate the to 90 degrees. But that's not what I want. I want to load two different images i.e. one image url will be for portrait mode and the other will be for landscape mode. I tried detecting orientation change and then loading the images accordingly. This didn't worked. In landscape mode also, the portrait images were loading. Any suggestions?

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment{

    Button next, previous;
    ProportionalImageView imageView;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentone, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        next = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.next);
        previous = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.previous);
        imageView = (ProportionalImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);

        Picasso.with(getActivity())
                .load("http://i.imgur.com/h5iwVmh.jpg")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(imageView);



        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((ViewPager) ((MainActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.pager)).setCurrentItem(1);
            }
        });

        previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((ViewPager) ((MainActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.pager)).setCurrentItem(-1);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load("http://i.imgur.com/H0IXUy0.jpg")
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .into(imageView);

        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load("http://i.imgur.com/h5iwVmh.jpg")
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .into(imageView);


        }
    }








}
```

Comment: Did you check if your onConfigurationChanged even gets fired? and the code flow work correct

Comment: It works well in portrait. When I try to change the mode to landscape, it still loads the portrait image url.

Comment: can you write some logcat in the `if else` inside `onConfigurationChanged` for checking the app detect correct orrientation

Comment: Yes. I checked using Toast. Its getting fired.

Comment: please try my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code for get the orientation

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)    context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int rotation = display.getRotation();
```

and load the image according rotation condition. exm :-  if(rotation== your condition) {   }

**you can also use to below code:**

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // refresh the instructions image
    ImageView instructions = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_instructions);

   if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //load image in picasso here
    } else {
        //load image in picasso here
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you get on screen horizontal and on screen vertical

Comment: In portrait mode, the correct image loads but in landscape mode, the same image is displayed. It doesn't loads the url which it should. @Bhunnu

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you rotate the device the `onViewCreated` is called again (but it called after `onConfigurationChanged` called)

In your code, the image have changed to landscape `onConfigurationChanged`, but after that the image change to portrait when `onViewCreated` called. This is the reason why you always have portrait image

Therefore you should change the image in `onViewCreated` instead of in `onConfigurationChanged`

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // load you landscape image
    }
    else {
       // load your portrait image
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: I tried it but still its loading the same image in landscape mode.